# Need help fixing segmentation fault in C++ while using Breadth First Search Algorithm

Tags: c++

I am using the BFS to try and find a pathway through a maze I created. The maze is a 6x6 2d array that consists of dashes that looks like this:

```
XpX--X
X---X-
XXX---
X---X-
X--XXX
-----S
```

The dashes are empty spaces and the X's are walls. The p is a start space and the S is the end space. I am getting a segmentation fault and am not 100% sure why. If anyone could figure this out that would be great thanks. Im new to coding so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Pos
{
  int x;
  int y;
  Pos *prev;
};

Pos start;
Pos finish;

string maze [6][6];
bool visited[6][6];

queue<Pos> mazeQueue;
int current;

void read()
{
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  char c;
  char str[256];
  ifstream is("maze.txt");
  
  while (is.get(c))
  {
    if (x < 6)
    {
      maze[y][x] = c;
      x++;
    }
    else
    {
      y++;
      maze[y][x] = c;
      x = 0;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
      for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
      {
        cout << " " << maze[i][j] << " ";
        visited[i][j] = false;

        if (maze[i][j] == "p")
        {
          start.x = i;
          start.y = j;
          start.prev = NULL;
          visited[i][j] = true;
        }

        if (maze[i][j] == "S")
        {
          finish.x = i;
          finish.y = j;
          finish.prev = NULL;
        }

        if (maze[i][j] == "X")
        {
          visited[i][j] = true;
        }
      }
    cout<<"\n";
  }

  cout << endl << endl;
}

void run()
{
  Pos *current;
  mazeQueue.push(start);

  while (!mazeQueue.empty())
  {
    current = &mazeQueue.front();
    mazeQueue.pop();

    if (current -> x == finish.x && current -> y == finish.y)
    {
      current = current -> prev;

      while (current -> prev != NULL)
      {
        maze[current -> x][current -> y] = "|";
        current = current -> prev;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; i < 6; j++)
        {
          cout << maze[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      
      if ((current -> y + 1 < 6) && (!visited[current -> x][current -> y + 1]))
      {
        visited[current -> x][current -> y + 1] = true;
        Pos temp;
        temp.x = current -> x;
        temp.y = current -> y + 1;
        temp.prev = current;
        mazeQueue.push(temp);
      }
    
      if ((current -> y - 1 >= 0) && (!visited[current -> x][current -> y - 1]))
      {
        visited[current -> x][current -> y - 1] = true;
        Pos temp;
        temp.x = current -> x;
        temp.y = current -> y - 1;
        temp.prev = current;
        mazeQueue.push(temp);
      }

      if ((current -> x - 1 >= 0) && (!visited[current -> x - 1][current -> y]))
      {
        visited[current -> x - 1][current -> y] = true;
        Pos temp;
        temp.x = current -> x - 1;
        temp.y = current -> y;
        temp.prev = current;
        mazeQueue.push(temp);
      }

      if ((current -> x + 1 < 6) && (!visited[current -> x + 1][current -> y]))
      {
        visited[current -> x + 1][current -> y] = true;
        Pos temp;
        temp.x = current -> x + 1;
        temp.y = current -> y;
        temp.prev = current;
        mazeQueue.push(temp);
      }
      
    }
  } 
}


int main()
{
  read();
  run();
}
```

Comment: In the first `while` you are writing to the array when `x = 6`.

Comment: Maybe you want to put `x = 0;` before `maze[y][x] = c;` instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

In your `read` function, there are several issues.

You don't have any error checking, so if the file fails to open you'll still try to read from it.

When you do read a character, you don't check its value. When you get to the end of a line, you'll read the `\n` character and go on merrily adding it to your maze. Since you don't ever check to see if you've reached the end of the maze, you can continue to read accessing past the end of `maze`, which will like cause a segfault.

The main problem is that you're not handling the `x` increment properly. You need to reset `x` before assigning to `maze[y][x]`. However, that loop body can be simplified by handling the rollover after writing to the current cell.

```cpp
  while (is.get(c))
  {
    maze[y][x] = c;
    if (++x == 6) {
      x = 0;
      ++y;
    }
  }
```

(I haven't added in the checks for invalid characters or reaching the end of the maze - that's left as an exercise for the reader.)

Other areas for improvement include not using hardcoded sizes (`6` - use a named constant instead), using global variables (they can all be encapsulated into a class), and changing from C-style arrays to Standard Library containers - `std::vector` or `std::array`.